# Open source library in Java for communicating with OPC HDA Server

Tags: java, opc

I am trying to create an application which entails communication with an **OPC HDA** server to get historical values of tags.
I was wondering if there are any free/open source libraries available in Java which can help me do that.

I have already tried the following options:

1. **Integration Objects Java Wrapper:** It internally uses **JNI**. When client and server are not co-located, it is difficult to get it working. It is licensed.
2. **jInterop:** Implements the **MSRPC** protocol and thus does not rely on JNI. Is portable. However, the OPC HDA interfaces are quite complex and I was not able to call them via **jInterop**. Also the errors that it throws are quite obscure, so troubleshooting is a major issue with this library. The call that I was not able to get working was the `IOPCHDA_SyncRead::ReadRaw.`
   For the reasons stated above, I am not keen on using both these libraries.

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Saurabh

Comment: Did you find any free lirbaries to get data from an OPC HDA server?

Comment: No I could not find any.